# deniedbysystem Windows.Devices

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm making a Windows store device app to go onto the auto play when my device is plugged in, However when I try to access any of the data from the app I keep getting `deniedBySystem`and I'm not sure how to access my device.

```
private async void OpenDevice()
{
   UInt32 vid = 1234;/*stand in vid and pid not real ones i  use in my code*/
   UInt32 pid = 5678;
   lstResults.Items.Clear();
   string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid, pid);
   int counter = 0;
   var myDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
   //var myDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs); /*I was using this but it wasn't returning any device*/
   for (int i = 0; i < myDevices.Count; i++)
   {
       try
       {
           if (myDevices[i].Id[4] == 'U' && myDevices[i].Id[8] == 'V' && myDevices[i].Id.Substring(12, 4) == vid.ToString())/* this if statements makes it so I only get the device I want*/
           {
               lstResults.Items.Add("VID " + myDevices[i].Id.Substring(12, 4) +
                    "          PID " + myDevices[i].Id.Substring(21, 4));
               counter++;
               var deciceAccessInfo = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromId(myDevices[i].Id);
               lstResults.Items.Add(deciceAccessInfo.CurrentStatus.ToString()); // this line informs me access is denied 
               //  lstResults.Items.Add(myDevices[i].Id);

               var usbDevice = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[i].Id);//this line returns usbDevice to equal null
           }
       }
       catch (Exception exception)
       {
           lstResults.Items.Add(exception.Message.ToString());
       }
   }
   lstResults.Items.Add(counter + " out of " + myDevices.Count + " Have the correct VID");
}
```

In the `Package.appxmanifest`I have checked all the capabilities in case it was one of them denieing me access but it wasn't. I have also tried running the program as an admin to see if that gave me access but no joy. so my question is what is denying me access and is there a way around it?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same

Comment: Unfortunately I did not resolve this issue and we had to ship the device without the app support.

Comment: Shame :( for me it seems to be because it uses usbser.sys to make a virtual serial port. SerialPorts are only supported in Win10 onwards. Despite the device being a cdc control which is OK for 8.1